# Automatically enter cell value, calculate difference in time and concert to decimal

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make a work issued overtime form work more efficiently.

Basically what I want to happen is when I put in my actual finish time in column E - Column D populates the same time as column C and column F calculates the difference between column D & E and formats it in decimal form.

Is this possible?

Thanks

[Spread sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zncT.png)

Comment: The answer to your question is: "Yes". Times are numbers, you can add and substract them. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you already have tried something please let us know, otherwise your question is not likely to receive a helpful answer as it is much more work to write a full script than to improve an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the following methods are helpful.

Formula 1: `=(E3-D3)*24`

Then you need to set the Total cell format to be "General".

[image]

Formula 2: `=(HOUR(E3)+MINUTE(E3)-HOUR(D3)-MINUTE(D3))/60`

[image]

You also need to set the Total cell format to be "General".